# Why was Luke behaving this way towards his mother in The Next Three Days?

Tags: character, the-next-three-days

In [*The Next Three Days*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1458175/), after Lara gets taken to jail, we see that her little son Luke refuses her in every scene up until the very end.

What is the reason for his behavioral change?

Comment: Too much trust in the idea that *"only bad people go to jail"* - which is probably drummed into kids by police who visit schools?

Answer (score 2):

His classmates were bullying him because of his mother being in prison. Near the beginning of the movie he is talking with his father about one particular case.

> John: But sam is your friend right?
>
> Luke: Not at lunch.
>
> John: What, did he steal your food?
>
> Luke: No.
>
> John: Did he say something mean about mom?
>
> Luke: Yeah.

Luke sees the consequences for him of his mother being in jail. He doesn't have control over the situation - he cannot make the bullies stop so, with the rationality of a 6 year old, he gets angry with his mother. He sees her being in jail as the real problem and ignores the fact that it's not her fault.

Once he sees her out of jail, he no longer has a reason to be angry at her.